# MVC Partial View on Dropdown change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a problem with a partial view in MVC project. Everything work fine for the first drop-down change, but from second partial view is loading twice, on 3rd is loading for three times and so on.
Can you you help me to see what i am missing? 
Or maybe give me a solution to a load a partial view depending on drop-down change to get information based on my selection?

Thank you!

Main view:

```
<div id="divProfile">
    @Html.Action("PartialOtherProfile","Home", new { uid = "uidkxxxx" })
</div>
```

Controller for partial view:

```
public PartialViewResult PartialOtherProfile(string uid)
        {
            if (uid != "uidkxxxx")
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserDB"]) == 0)
                {
                    return PartialView("NoAccessPage");
                }
                else
                {
                    UserEntities8 user = new UserEntities8();
                    var data =      user.GEt_USER_traseu_Other(uid.ToString()).ToList();
                    ViewBag.MasinaPersonala = data[0].MasinaPersonala;
                    ViewBag.Traseu_personal = data[0].Nume_statie;
                    ViewBag.NrTelefon = data[0].NrTelefon;

                    return PartialView("PartialOtherProfile");
                }
            }
            return PartialView("ChoosePerson");
        }
```

jQuery on change script:

```
$('#txtAlegeProfil').change(function () {
        var uid = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/PartialOtherProfile',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { uid: uid },
            success: function (result) {
                var div = $('#divProfile');
                div.html('');
                div.html(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What is your element with `id="txtAlegeProfil"`? Is that script in the main view or partial?

Comment: It is my drop-down id, located in main view.

Comment: use div.empty() instead of div.html('') and check with onchange="functionname()"

Comment: Chnage it's working. First change works fine, but on second my partial is loading for 2 times and so on.

Comment: I think post the full (or more detail) of the 'main' view that does the calling...the one with `txtAlegeProfil` and `divProfile` in it. There has to be something going on in there that is triggering multiple calls

Comment: I figured it out, finally. My mistake was that i used same javascript file for both, main and partial, i just put on change script only in my main view and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is intersted, the problem was that i used same javascript file for both, main and partial views. 
On change dropdown function must be in a javascript file used only in main view.

Comment: First comment on the question - _Is that script in the main view or partial?_ :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed that was in Both, main and partial, views. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `javascript` for `onchange`use MVC `onchage` property in the dropdown as HTML attribute

```
onchange = "document.location.href = '/Home/PartialOtherProfile?uid=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"
```